# How to integrate Google Classroom API with react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-api, google-classroom, google-api-js-client

I am struggling to find a way to integrate **Google classroom API** with **react-native** application.
I have gone through Google API documentation but I am unable to find a way to integrate this api into my react-native app.

**Option - 1**
https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/js
 the above is the link which says **Browser Quickstart** 
but I can not insert *Script* tag into my react-native app. and react-native is not browser so ultimately it won't work for react-native. so this option is for web I think.

**Option - 2**

https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/nodejs
**Node.js Quickstart** - this guide says it is for node.js, if you look into integration code it is complete node.js code which will require a node server to run. it is only for server side node.js, it will also not work.

Then I have searched for any ready made NPM packages but which is also not available for react-native. No official google npm to use in react-native application.

I also found a way use Gapi API. it won't help
Gapi - [How to use gapi in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977448/how-to-use-gapi-in-react)

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance :)