# How do I use the Google Classroom API in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-classroom

So basically: I have used google oauth2 to be able to login the user with google classroom api scopes (such as classroom.courses.readonly) using the react-google-login module. However: how would I get data such as the user's courses/student rosters in those courses?

FYI: I'm trying to get a list of the user's courses and lists of the students inside those courses.
I would appreciate any help given, I've been working on this issue for many days now.

Heres the React code:

```js
import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';

const clientID = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID;

const onGoogleSuccess = (res) => {
    console.log(res);
    window.localStorage.setItem('token', res.tokenId);
}
```

```html
<GoogleLogin 
    clientId={clientID}
    buttonText="Login"
    onSuccess={onGoogleSuccess}
    cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
    scope="openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly"
    isSignedIn={true}
/>
```

Comment: Maybe this will be of help to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977448/how-to-use-gapi-in-react

Comment: @RafaGuillermo How would I use that with google classroom api tho? I tried using the googleapis npm module in react but it uses fs so it throws an error.

Comment: What error does it throw and what code throws it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the react-gapi library

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).