# Import external JS library and use it inside React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have some code in React like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  TICautocapture(etc..);
```

That `TICautocapture()` function is already defined in an external js file, let's say:

```
http:://some-cdn.example.com/library.js
```

So how could I use that `library` methods on my React component?

I need it to be declared inside the Component, otherwise it wont find the name of the function.

by the way, I cant download the file locally because the library is being updated constantly, so I need to import from an external url.

EDIT:

The code of the library is like this:

```
// http:://some-cdn.example.com/library.js

var TICautocapture = (function(){
  var lib = {...}
  var error_handler;
  var handleError = (error_code, error_callback) => {...}
  function autocapture(container, options){...}

  return autocapture;
})();

if(window.jQuery){
  (function($){
    $.fn.autocapture = function(options){
      TICautocapture(this.attr('id'), options);
    }
  }(jQuery));
}
```

And from there I need to use the `TICautocapture()` method.

Comment: probably with [Webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)

Comment: @LindaPaiste Could you elaborate? I have read that link but I can't find any info about how add external URLs

Comment: why not loading the js with `axios` are else. And then wait for the promise to be resolved.

Comment: @Sysix how is that? I will update the code of the external library that I need to use

Comment: Well now I'm not sure if that's the right way if you are just using the package in this component.  The webpack externals is a way to make webpack aware of functions that are available in the window/global scope.  It's expecting that the scripts are loaded via the `<script>` tag in your HTML.

Comment: You might want to try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42872625/10431574

Answer (score 1):

Your file is loading `var TICautocapture` into the global scope and also setting a property `autocapture` on `window.jQuery.fn`.

I am not confident that this is correct, but I would try using [Webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) by putting the following in your `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  externalsType: 'script',
  externals: {
    autocapture: [
      'http://some-cdn.example.com/library.js',
      'autocapture', // or maybe 'TICautocapture'?
      'TICautocapture',
    ],
  },
};
```

And then try importing it in your component file:

```
import {TICautocapture} from "autocapture";
```

Comment: I'm having errors with the `externalsType` options: `- configuration has an unknown property 'externalsType'. These properties are valid... etc`, and also, without that key, I'm getting a `unexpected token }` whne I try to render the web

Answer (score -1):

If it's just a file you have in the project, you can simply import it to where you need like so:

```js
// if it's the default export
import TICautocapture from "./file.js";
```

or

```js
// if it's NOT the default export and other 
// functions and variables could be imported from that file
import { TICautocapture } from "./file.js";
```

Of course, in the cases I mentioned, you should make sure they're exported in the files they're exported using `export` or `export default`.

If the file is being delivered by a CDN, I'm not really sure but I think just by adding it the the root HTML file will make it available everywhere for you.

Comment: It's not in the project, like i said, is an external file from an external URL, I can't download it and add to to my project. I need to use it directly from the server.

Comment: Plus, look at the code of my question there are not exports, just a `var`with a function that I need to use

Comment: Once the file is loaded you should be able to access `window.jQuery.fn.autocapture` or `window.TICautocapture` since `var TICautocapture` is in the global scope.

Comment: This  does not answer the question.